# NullPointerException when adding data - Java

Tags: java, tree, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree

I have a following question.

I am implementing BST - Binary Search Tree.

Let's say that I have 3 classes: **Employee**, **Node** and **Tree**.

I am trying to get access from **Node** class to **Employee** class elements (fields).


Here is some code:

**Employee class**

```
public class Employee
{
   public String name;
   public int age;
}
```

**Node class**

```
public class Node
{
   public Employee empl;

   public Node left;
   public Node right; 
}
```

**Tree class**

```
public class Tree
{
   private Node root;

   public Tree()
   {
      root = null;
   }
   public void insert()
   {
      Node newNode = new Node();

      Scanner readName = new Scanner(System.in);
      newNode.empl.name = readName.nextLine();

      Scanner readAge = new Scanner(System.in);
      newNode.empl.age = readAge.nextInt();

      // Add to the tree code
      // ...
   }
}
```

So, the problem is, when I am adding name it gives me an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at Node.<init>(Node.java)
at Tree.insert(Tree.java)
at Tree.menu(Tree.java)
at Main.main(Main.java)
```

Maybe it's because i did not add constructors? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the Employee object will be null.

```
newNode.empl.name
---------^
```

empl is Employee object which is not initialised.

Update the `Node` class as below :

```
public class Node
{
   public Employee empl = new Employee();  // Before it was not initialised

   public Node left;
   public Node right; 
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, unfortunately I can't give you +1

Comment: hehehehe @user3348027.Its okk dear.